# heroku "script/rails: Permission denied"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

> heroku run -a app script/rails console

gives:

```
Running `script/rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.3422
bash: script/rails: Permission denied
```

am on Windows 8 ...

```
heroku version
heroku/toolbelt/2.41.0 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

needed to add "ruby" after app and before command ...

```
heroku run -a my-app ruby script/rails console

Running `ruby script/rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.5473

... various deprecation warnings re "You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! 

Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.11)
irb(main):001:0>
```

(clue was provided from [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.rails.heroku/176) )

Comment: If console is what you want then can't you just do `heroku run rails console`?

Comment: right, that worked. So https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/console-bamboo is a dud